# Use Ascii string as value of a environment variable in spring-boot app

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, encoding

In my spring boot application, I've defined a template field in a ConfigurationProperties with a default value (in Ascii):

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties("app.template")
public class AppTemplateProps {

    String greeting = "\u00bfQu\u00e9 est\u00e1s haciendo %s?";

}
```

The value of `AppTemplateProps.greeting` is correct (is native):

```
¿Qué estás haciendo %s?
```

But when i define `app.template.greeting` environment variable with the same value, the value of `AppTemplateProps.greeting` is incorrect (is not native):

```
\u00bfQu\u00e9 est\u00e1s haciendo %s?
```

So what should i do to get the correct (native) value from environment variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ASCII is an encoding that defines only 95 characters, and doesn't include the `á` or the `é` or the `¿`. Therefore what you say is not possible; java strings aren't ASCII, which is why that `greeting` part does work. So, yeah, if you want to store a `é` in ASCII ordinarily you cannot do that; *within java source files* there is the `\u` mechanism, but... that only works in source code. You can't just read a string and magically have this stuff applied for you.

There is no easy answer - either make sure your inputs are UTF_8 based, and just stick the `é` and friends in there, or, write some code that applies `\u` decoding. JSON strings support this as well, so that's one way. You could also write some code to do this; it's not particularly complicated.